# how to make a more complex tag in playframework templating #{field}?

Tags: playframework

We have duplicate code all over the place and we want to be able to change all that code in one place(we are testing a port from seam to playframework).  I would like to create a tag file for this(I have created a few tags already in play but this one is more difficult).  Here is the code repeating right now....

```
<div>
    <div class="entry">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    #{field 'company.alias'}
    <span class="label ${field.errorClass}">Company Alias:</span>
    <span class="input ${field.errorClass}">
        <input type="text" class="boxtpl" name="${field.name}" value="${company?.alias}">
        <a id="newinfo" class="help" title="&{'help.companyAlias'}">Help</a>
        <span class="error">${field.error}</span>
    </span>
    #{/field}
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="entry">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    #{field 'company.name'}
    <span class="label ">Company Name:</span>
    <span class="input ">
        <input type="text" class="boxtpl" name="${field.name}" value="${company?.name}">
        <a id="newinfo" class="help" title="&{'help.companyName'}">Help</a>
        <span class="error">${field.error}</span>
    </span>
    #{/field}
    </div>
</div>
```

Usage of the new tag would be like so (or something like this if we can manage it somehow)....

```
#{mynewtag label:'Company Name', name:'company.name', help:&{'help.companyName'}}
#{mynewtag label:'Company Alias', name:'company.alias', help:&{'help.companyAlias'}}
```

so notice, the field 'company.name' so I want that to be fed into the tag, and notice the value="${company?.name}" so want that part to be fed in, and then finally the &{'help.companyName'}  (basically 3 locations as I know how to do the 4th which is the label).  Then, when we change this layout, it changes all over our pages.  Is there a way to accomplish this in play or no?

It would be very nice, if there was a #{field.value} like the #{field.name} so I would only have to pass in three paramters instead of 4.

Also, when it comes to accessibility, I guess I can easily add the for attribute at a later time for all fields using this tag template without having to edit 100's of fields on different pages.

Comment: Are you trying to refactor your "field" tag or do you want to create a new tag, let's call it "entry", that prints out the "entry" `div` with the surrounding `div` and the nested "field" tag?

Comment: I simply want to change the above code into ONE tag file and use it like so  #{mynewtag label:'Company Name', name:'company.name', help:&{'help.companyName'}} AND #{mynewtag label:'Company Alias', name:'company.alias', help:&{'help.companyAlias'}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your own tag to do that. Here is the basics for what you want. You can modify it after to add optional values and other things you want to pass to the tag

```
public class InputTag extends FastTags {

public static void _input(Map<?, ?> args, Closure body,
        PrintWriter out,
        ExecutableTemplate template,
        int fromLine) {
    String _name = args.get("name").toString();
    String _label = args.get("label").toString();
    String _help = args.get("help") == null ? null : args.get("help").toString();
    play.data.validation.Error error = Validation.error(_name);

    String[] pieces = _name.split("\\.");
    Object _value = template.getProperty(pieces[0]);
    if (_value != null) {
        if (pieces.length > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < pieces.length; i++) {
                try {
                    Field f = _value.getClass().getField(pieces[i]);
                    if (i == (pieces.length - 1)) {
                        try {
                            Method getter = _value.getClass().getMethod(
                                    "get" + JavaExtensions.capFirst(f.getName()));
                            _value = getter.invoke(_value, new Object[0]);
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                            _value = f.get(_value).toString();
                        }
                    } else {
                        _value = f.get(_value);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // if problem reading the field dont set any value
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (_value == null) {
        _value = "";
    }
    out.println("<div>");
    out.println("<div class=\"entry\">");
    out.println("<div class=\"spacer\"></div>");
    out.println(String.format("  <span class=\"label\">%s</span>", _label));
    out.println("  <span class=\"input\">");
    out.println(String.format("    <input type=\"text\" class=\"boxtpl\" name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\">", _name, _value));
    out.println(String.format("<a id=\"newinfo\" class=\"help\" title=\"%s\">Help</a>", Messages.get(_help)));
    out.println(String.format("<span class=\"error\">%s</span>", (error == null ? "" : error.message())));
    out.println("  </span>");
    out.println("</div>");
}
}
```